# From_unixtime in derby and hsqldb

Tags: mysql, hibernate, junit, hsqldb, derby

I am using derby and hsqldb for unit testing my code. In my code, i am using HQL (hibernate query language). In those queries, i am using from_unixtime(timestamp) to extract datetime from timestamp. It seems that derby anf hsqldb don't support from_unixtime. Also, seems to me that from_unixtime is mysql specific function. How correct is that? How can i test my hql query (which contains from_unixtime(timestamp) function using derby or hsqldb?

Answer (score 2):

FROM_UNIXTIME is indeed specific to MySQL.

HSQLDB 2.2.6 and later supports this function to convert a unix time (in seconds) to a datetime value:

```
TIMESTAMP( <second value> )
```

For example:

call timestamp( 1000000000) returns 2001-09-09 01:46:40.0

HSQLDB 2.2.6 also supports a MySQL syntax compatibility mode, which includes several automatic conversions for SQL statements written for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

In Derby, you may be able to use the JDBC escape function TIMESTAMPADD to add your interval in seconds to the base timestamp of January 1, 1970. Here's some docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html Here's some discussion of translating back and forth between the MySQL techniques and the Derby techniques: http://objectmix.com/apache/646986-mysql-to_days-emulation-derby.html